# dialogflow v2 OAuth using rest api

Tags: angular, rest, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, google-oauth

I'm trying to integrate dialog-flow v2 in ionic. It says for v2 we have use Oauth2.0. So, when I want to get the token by the url it's asking me sign-in with google account to get the token. But I don't want to sign-in with google. So, how can I do this?
This is the url I'm making request for

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=token&client_id=xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform&redirect_uri=http://localhost

Comment: if you do not want to sign in, you will have to provide a `grant_type` and relevant credentials.

Comment: what kind of credentials? I have created a webclient and got the client_id.

Comment: you may want to check documentation for oauth2 and google api